# How to identify class is existing or not in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my web application ,i need to hide the content part when i click a button .
So i have 5 navigation options on my top right side. But out of 5 for of them using same class name for content part becoz all these contents are generating dynamically in cake php mvc project.  So When i click button i need to hide that content part its working for all 4 navigation(class name:col1-9) except one (have different class name  :col1-2).

i tried to check that class existing on html before using jquery css to hide that part ,but it is checking only the true case not the else part(class not exist).

```
$('.notifications').click(function(){

    if ($('.col1-9').length >0){
        alert('different navigation');  //This is working    for 4 navigation options
    } else if ($('.col1-2').length){
        alert('different g navigation');  //This is not working for remaining 1 navigation otion
    }

});
```

Comment: How can a length be less than zero?  I think your answer lies in the answer to that.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Beat me to it! Change the length check to be `if (!$('.col1-2').length) {`

Comment: but the else part wont work

Comment: @Bangalore Do you mean an if else statement like this? http://pastebin.com/xVjrmyAa

Comment: yes sam u r correct..i want somethng like that

Comment: @Bangalore Can you update your example to include a jsfiddle link? Its is difficult to tell what your intended result is supposed to be

Comment: @Bangalore did any of the answers help or are solutions to your question?

Answer (score 0):

change your if statement to:

```
$('.col1-2').length <1
```

Comment: The OP has stated in the comments that isnt the fix he needs. Also you can write this cleaner by writing `if (!$('.col1-2').length)`

Comment: @Bangalore you need to clarify a bit.. is this what you want: if '.col1-9' exists, do the first 'if', if it doesn't and '.col1-2' exists, do the the 'else'.. ? that's what you want?

Comment: if col1-9  exist then execute only that part and if col1-2 exist then execute col1-2 part

Comment: could it be while col1-2 exists, col1-9 exists also?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You need them to be separate if statements, meaning:

```
$('.notifications').click(function(){
    // Moved these out into variable just for cleaner code
    var col1to9 = $('.col1-9').length;
    var col1to2 = $('.col1-2').length;

    if (col1to9 && !col1to2){
        alert('different navigation'); 
    } 

    if (col1to2 && !col1to9){
        alert('different g navigation');  
        }

});
```

So, Like you wrote in webkit's comments: "if col1-9 exist then execute only that part and if col1-2 exist then execute col1-2 part".

If you want the second if statement to always execute whenever `$('.col1-2').length` is true, even if `$('.col1-9').length` is also true just remove the second condition. So it'll look like this:

```
      if (col1to2){
        alert('different g navigation');  
      }
```